# How to exclude files with a filename wildcard using forfiles and xocpy

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that scans dir for .ips files and uploads them to unc path however, I want to exclude specific names from the upload.

Example:

```
CoreTime*.ips
UIKit*.ips
proactive*.ips
JetsamEvent*.ips
```

The following would work but i cant get it to work with the forfiles cmd correctly and nor can i get robocopy to do this.

```
grep -v "CoreTime\|UIKit\|proactive\|JetsamEvent"
```

Batch File:

```
Echo Checking %Logs% for .ips files
PushD "%Logs%" &&(
forfiles -s -m *.ips -d -30 -c "cmd /c xcopy /C /Y @path \\UNC_Path\ips\%username%"
 ) & PopD
```

Comment: `XCopy` has an `/EXCLUDE:file` option where `file` contains a list of exclusions one per line. However you don't really need `ForFiles` for this because `RoboCopy` has a `/MINAGE:` option and a `/XF` option so should be able to perform this task more efficiently. Please open a Command Prompt window, enter `robocopy /?` and read the output usage information.

Comment: its my understanding that the exclude file cant have wildcards in the name as example Filename_something.ips > filename*.ips

Comment: The list items in `XCopy`'s `/Exclude` option `file` are wildcards, and similarly `RoboCopy`'s `/XF` items. It shouldn't be too difficult for you to create a small test environment and try them to see what happens!

Comment: _N. B.:_ `popd` should be within the parentheses `)` behind `pushd ... && (` to ensure it is not executed when the former fails...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Compo,

include:

```
robocopy C:\SRC \\DST_UNC KeyWord1*.ips KeyWord2*.ips KeyWord1*.crash KeyWord2*.crash /S
```

OR

exclude:

```
robocopy C:\SRC \\DST_UNC *.ips *.crash /S /XF stacks*.* /XF periodic*.* /XF CoreTime*.* /S /XF UIKit*.* /XF proactive*.*
```

Comment: What happened to your date filtering?